# How to embed script in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use below code in my website.

```
<div class="playpass playpass-widget">
  <script src="https://playpass.com/widgets/R2wqxme.js"></script>
  <p>Schedule created with <a href="https://playpass.com/sports-software/football-schedule-maker">football scheduler</a> by Playpass</p>
</div>
```

If I place this code in raw html it works. However in Angular it doesn't. I tried DomSanitizer and SafeHtml but it didn't work. How can I run this embed on my Angular app?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `script` part inside the `index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
  ....
   <script src="https://playpass.com/widgets/R2wqxme.js"></script>
  ....
</head>
</html>
```

Then, in your component you need to declare your functions like this:

```
declare var myExtFunction: any;
declare var webGlObject: any;
```

Then you can use it!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer but I don't understand myExtFunction and webGlObject. How can I use them or bind to my html component?

Comment: That are function in your imported script. I used only demo names. You need to declare your exported functions to can use it in angular (typescript)